# How can I build and install vpnc or similar VPN client in CoreOS?

Tags: vpn, coreos

How can I build and install [vpnc](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) in [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/)?  `vpnc` is a "Cisco-compatible VPN client" and is available in the Ubuntu Server package repository.  As CoreOS doesn't include build tools such as `gcc`, `libc`, or `make`, it makes it difficult to build any applications for the operating system. Could I build vpnc and statically link all of the libraries it requires in Ubuntu and then install it in CoreOS?

Could I run `vpnc` in an Ubuntu container inside CoreOS that serves as a VPN gateway?

Comment: No explanation for the down vote?

Comment: Just guessing here, but: You didn't showed any research, you did on your own. Besides: "Product and learning material recommendations" are off-topic here. All the best!

Comment: There is not much to show.  CoreOS doesn't include `gcc`, `libc`, or `make`, which makes it difficult to build anything for the operating system.  I could try to statically build `vpnc` in Ubuntu and then install it in CoreOS, but there's no guarantee that it will work and I'm not sure that this is a recommended practise in CoreOS.  If I can't run a VPN client in CoreOS or a container, then I can't use CoreOS.

Comment: My search of the CoreOS Dev mailing list turned up five or six "vpn" hits, but none were of much help.  Google wasn't much help, either.

Comment: Maybe put these information into your question.

Comment: Never used CoreOS personally, so my knowledge is de facto non existent, but: Couldn't you do the build process somewhere else, using a OS which provides all the needed tools?

Comment: I could try.  Just not sure if it would work in CoreOS.  The option most likely to succeed would be a static build which includes all of the required libraries.

Comment: Just try it out. Besides: I think you've better chances to get answers posting to a specific CoreOS mailing list. The statistics for [coreos] here on SF aren't that impressive: 36 followers, 152 questions.

Comment: CoreOS doesn't have build tools because you're not supposed to build things for it. Instead, you're supposed to create a rube goldberg contraption of containers and networks, and rebuild it when they completely change everything every few releases. Welcome to the future.

Comment: Removed solicitation of "product and learning material recommendations" from question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussion [*Build and run vpnc on CoreOS?*](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/coreos-dev/-jTf_5gGePw/discussion) on forum [CoreOS Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreos-dev) suggested two solutions:

1. [Build the binary on Ubuntu and copy it to CoreOS.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/coreos-dev/-jTf_5gGePw/r0CpQCZaCgAJ)
2. [Run `vpnc` in its own container and run this container and the application container using the VPN within the same pod.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/coreos-dev/-jTf_5gGePw/JroLauOMCgAJ)

Answer (score 1):

There is an impressive amount of junk to read through to find info about how to do things like this on CoreOS. From what I can tell, you should be creating a container for anything you want to run on this OS (as per it's design) unless you want to modify CoreOS itself.

Perhaps this will help you create an application container

https://coreos.com/blog/getting-started-with-rkt-1.0.html

Modifying SDK - Developer guide

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sdk-modifying-coreos.html

Comment: Does it make sense to create a vpnc container whose sole responsibility is to connect to a VPN on behalf of other containers? Would this even work?

Comment: I have no idea, but creating a container is how coreos handles software "packaging". I'd have to know more to help, sorry.